# What do you call the Variance from zero from zero instead of the mean? What do you call the Standard Deviation from zero?

Tags: statistics, terminology, standard-deviation, variance

Normally a variance is calculated towards the mean ($\bar X_n$), so it looks like this:

$$
o^2_n = \frac{\sum_{i = 1} ^ n (X_i - \bar X_n)^2}{n}
$$

What if we replace that mean by zero (even though the mean is not zero). What do you call this?

$$
o^2_n = \frac{\sum_{i = 1} ^ n (X_i)^2}{n}
$$

*Context: This formula is very useful for load balancing tasks as fairly as possible across workers/machines. The resulting number is higher if it is less fair. Unlike normal variance (or std dev), fairness focuses on the heaviest loaded worker/machine first.*

And what do you call the square root of that formula?

Comment: I think you are after the [moment about $0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)).  (Not aware of a standard name for the square root of a moment).

Comment: For a sample I don't know whether there's a standard name (by the way, for a sample you'd usually divide by $n-1$, not $n$). For a distribution the expected value of $X^2$ is also called the second moment of $X$.

Comment: Look up the distinction between 'central' and 'noncentral' moments. This distinction applies to both sample and population moments.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen it called the mean square. I don't know another name for it. Its square root is called the root mean square, or root-mean-square.

**PS:** Following "lulu" 's comment, it is of course also called the second moment. I think I missed that because I think  of "second moment" as meaning $\operatorname{E}(X^2),$ and "second sample moment" as meaning $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2/n,$ where $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ is a sample rather than the whole population.